# Terminal package-lock.json

Tags: javascript, json, angular, terminal

I am taking an online coding class and I just started learning my way through Terminal. I was trying to run a npm test but could not figure out why I was getting an error. I looked up different ways to solve it but it only made things worse as I have changed the package.json file into package-lock.json somehow.
 Is there a way I could undo this? 
Below is the command that I typed:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here.
Each part of your command does the following

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
```

will uninstall the angular command line interface globally (this is what -g does).

```
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
```

will uninstall the angular command line interface, and remove from devdependencies within your package.json file.

these two above are the same command apart from the extra arguments.

And then after that you are globally reinstalling the latest angular cli ??

Futhermore for future reference, in order to chain commands you need to add  '&&' between the npm commands for one line

Hope that clears something up